# Performance: Replacing Series values with keys from a Dictionary in Python

Tags: performance, for-loop, python-3.6

I have a data series that contains various names of the same organizations.  I want harmonize these names into a given standard using a mapping dictionary.  I am currently using a nested for loop to iterate through each series element and if it is within the dictionary's values, I update the series value with the dictionary key.

```
# For example, corporation_series is:
0 'Corp1'
1 'Corp-1'
2 'Corp 1'
3 'Corp2'
4 'Corp--2'
dtype: object

# Dictionary is:
mapping_dict = { 
    'Corporation_1': ['Corp1', 'Corp-1', 'Corp 1'],
    'Corporation_2': ['Corp2', 'Corp--2'],
}

# I use this logic to replace the values in the series
for index, value in corporation_series.items():
    for key, list in mapping_dict.items():
        if value in list:
            corporation_series = corporation_series.replace(value, key)
```

So, if the series has a value of 'Corp1', and it exists in the dictionary's values, the logic replaces it with the corresponding key of corporations.  However, it is an extremely expensive method.  Could someone recommend me a better way of doing this operation?  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by using python's .map function.  In order to use .map, I had to invert my dictionary:

```
# Inverted Dict:
mapping_dict = { 
    'Corp1': ['Corporation_1'],
    'Corp-1': ['Corporation_1'],
    'Corp 1': ['Corporation_1'],
    'Corp2': ['Corporation_2'],
    'Corp--2':['Corporation_2'],
}

# use .map
corporation_series.map(newdict)
```

Instead of 5 minutes of processing, took around 5s.  While this is works, I sure there are better solutions out there.  Any suggestions would be most welcome.